# setting pd option to show all rows and cols not working

Tags: python

**I have a simple function that returns a dataframe. I would like return the dataframe with all its columns and rows in the nicest format possible .**

```
pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', 1000)

aggs = ['min', 'mean', 'median', 'max']
aggs_col = [col for col in X_cr.columns]

def custom_group(df,aggregators,aggregate_columns):
  d={}
  for i in range(len(aggregate_columns)):
    d[aggregate_columns[i]]=aggregators
  df_other = df.groupby(['A']).agg(d)
  return print(df_other.T)

custom_group(df,aggs,aggs_col)
```

Im not sure why the option_context doesnt apply with my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.option_context()` is a context manager. Your function call should be with in the context manager.

```
Example:

Latitude = [9.5386, 9.5383, 9.5283, 9.4847, 9.4847, 9.4839]
Longitude = [139.9222]*6
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 3, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.width', 100):
   pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)
   pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 3)
   pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 2)

   df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Latitude, Longitude)), columns=["Latitude","Longitude"])
   print(df)
```

Comment: Great..Thank you!